# How dose the bitcoin locking/unlocking script work?

Tags: bitcoin

When I read the book *[Mastering Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook)* [chapter 6](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch06.asciidoc#P2PubKHash2)

I try to follow the steps mentioned in this book, but I found out the result is not correct, where am I wrong?

[image: A step-by-step execution of the combined script]

The transaction is [here](https://blockchain.info/tx/0627052b6f28912f2703066a912ea577f2ce4da4caa5a5fbd8a57286c345c2f2):

Input Scripts:

```
ScriptSig: 
PUSHDATA(72)[3045022100884d142d86652a3f47ba4746ec719bbfbd040a570b1deccbb6498c75c4ae24cb02204b9f039ff08df09cbe9f6addac960298cad530a863ea8f53982c09db8f6e381301] 
PUSHDATA(65)[0484ecc0d46f1918b30928fa0e4ed99f16a0fb4fde0735e7ade8416ab9fe423cc5412336376789d172787ec3457eee41c04f4938de5cc17b4a10fa336a8d752adf]
```

Then I track the [output](https://blockchain.info/tx-index/47852783/0) that is included in this transaction. In which the output scripts like this:

```
DUP HASH160 PUSHDATA(20)[7f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a8] EQUALVERIFY CHECKSIG
```

Then I calculate the `RIPMED160(SHA256(Pubk)) = "6df13de1f1d824380834e0d42e49e5e451a647cf"`using the [website calculator](http://www.md5calc.com/ripemd160)

But the result is not equal to 7f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a8 in output script.

Comment: This is very similar to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37040/ripemd160sha256publickey-where-am-i-going-wrong and makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but I think you are hashing the hex string, not the binary data. If I calculate ripemd160(sha256(pubk)) using Python's hashlib library I get the correct result:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import binascii, hashlib
>>> sha256 = hashlib.new('sha256')
>>> ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
>>> sha256.update(binascii.unhexlify('0484ecc0d46f1918b30928fa0e4ed99f16a0fb4fde0735e7ade8416ab9fe423cc5412336376789d172787ec3457eee41c04f4938de5cc17b4a10fa336a8d752adf'))
>>> ripemd160.update(sha256.digest())
>>> ripemd160.hexdigest()
'7f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a8'
```

Comment: Thanks,I get correct result by using your function.